# showing all dates in SQL query and not only lisitng dates which appear in table

Tags: mariadb, query

I have a query which I then usu to populate a graph to give a graphical representation of number of jobs booked per day

```
SELECT COUNT(DateBooked) AS jobs, DATE_FORMAT(DateBooked, '%d-%M') AS date,  '#00b300' as colour 
FROM Table1
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DateBooked, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m') AND JobStatus != 'Quoted' and JobStatus != 'Archived' and JobStatus != 'Sourcing'
GROUP BY DateBooked
Order By DateBooked ASC
```

Works great and shows me how many jobs have been booked.

The thing it doesnt show me is days where no jobs have been booked.
Ideally, I would like the output to display all dates up to and including the current date even if no jobs have been booked.

The part I am struggling with, is... if no job has been booked on a day then that days date will not be in the table

For example is table1 looked like

| id | DateBooked | Job Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/04/2023 | ..... |
| 2 | 01/04/2023 | ..... |
| 3 | 02/04/2023 | ..... |
| 4 | 04/04/2023 | ..... |
| 5 | 04/04/2023 | ..... |
| 6 | 04/04/2023 | ..... |

I would like the query to return

| DateBooked | COUNT(DateBooked |
| --- | --- |
| 01/04/2023 | 2 |
| 02/04/2023 | 1 |
| 03/04/2023 | 0 |
| 04/04/2023 | 3 |

04/04/2023 was not listed in `Table1` but still appears in the output because it falls within the date sequence

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB you can use  recursive common table expressions to generate a list of dates. The following example generate missing dates for every month.

Query

```
with recursive all_dates(dates) as (
    select date_add(date_add(LAST_DAY(current_date()),interval 1 DAY),interval -1 MONTH) dates
    union all 
    select dates + interval 1 day from all_dates where dates < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
 )
select * from all_dates order by dates
```

*The table refreshes at the start of each month, so it only shows data for the current month*

Change the where condition to

```
WHERE DateBooked >= date_add(date_add(LAST_DAY(current_date()),interval 1 DAY),interval -1 MONTH) and DateBooked <= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Change those repeating AND conditions to

```
AND JobStatus not in ('Quoted','Archived','Sourcing')
```

Final query

```
with recursive fill_dates(dates) as (
        select date_add(date_add(LAST_DAY(current_date()),interval 1 DAY),interval -1 MONTH) dates
        union all 
        select dates + interval 1 day from fill_dates where dates <  LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
    )
    select DATE_FORMAT(dates, '%d-%M') AS date_,
           COUNT(DateBooked) AS jobs 
    FROM fill_dates 
    LEFT JOIN table1 on fill_dates.dates=table1.DateBooked and JobStatus not in ('Quoted','Archived','Sourcing')
    GROUP BY date_
```

Consider the following data examples which can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/p1XTZRkS) as well

```
create table table1(
  id int,
  DateBooked date ,
  JobDetails varchar(25),
  JobStatus varchar(25) );

insert into table1 (id,DateBooked,JobStatus) values
(1,'2023-04-01','Live'),
(2,'2023-04-01','Live'),
(3,'2023-04-02','Live'),
(4,'2023-04-04','Test'),
(5,'2023-04-04','Quoted'),
(6,'2023-04-04','Quoted'),
(7,'2023-05-02','Live');
```

> Result
>
> ```
> date_ jobs
> 01-April  2
> 02-April  1
> 03-April  0
> 04-April  1
> 05-April  0
> 06-April  0
> 07-April  0
> 08-April  0
> 09-April  0
> 10-April  0
> 11-April  0
> 12-April  0
> 13-April  0
> 14-April  0
> 15-April  0
> 16-April  0
> 17-April  0
> 18-April  0
> 19-April  0
> 20-April  0
> 21-April  0
> 22-April  0
> 23-April  0
> 24-April  0
> 25-April  0
> 26-April  0
> 27-April  0
> 28-April  0
> 29-April  0
> 30-April  0
> ```

Comment: The table refreshes at the start of each month, so it only shows data for the current month.
Would this still work for that case? Or would I need to generate a new list of dates each month?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ill give that a try

Comment: Im not getting the expected outcome
What I am getting is

`|affectedRows|`
`|---------------|`
`|    30              |`

Comment: The filter `DATE_FORMAT(DateBooked, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m')` is used because that shows only entries in the current month, without.
From the table it pulls only data which matched the current Month & Year. Without that filter it was giving me outputs from all months

Comment: Why would it return `affectedRows` if it was not an update query. thats given me a slight fear

Comment: I know that, I thought you were asking why I had used it in my query in the question, so was just explaining my reasoning. I did not use it  when replicating your query

Should I be concerned about the `affectedRow` responce? I have only ever seen this in an update query

Comment: @PaulMcF87 edited the question with a new updated answer which will give the desired result and will be dynamic for every month. No need to add where condition for the current month as it is handled by the cte

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB has a simple way to build a list of the desired dates.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/

It would go something like this for the *current* month.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM seq_1_to_31
    LEFT JOIN Table1
      ON CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-', seq) = Table1.DateBooked
    WHERE DateBooked > LEFT(CURDATE(), 7)
```

For last month, change `CURDATE()` to `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH` .